# Windows 10 flickering on Macbook Pro Late 2016 boot camp when not receiving input

Tags: windows-10, boot-camp

Whenever I boot into windows 10 through boot camp, the screen turns off as if going to sleep when I am not giving keyboard or mouse input. When I move the mouse constantly, the screen stays on and functions normally. Otherwise, the screen turns completely on and off intermittenly due to my typing not giving constant input, which is quite annoying. I have seen a lot of info that both Apple and Microsoft support blame each other and say it is not a problem on their end. How do I return my screen to normal?

Answer (score 0):

Found [a solution given by Armadylann121 on November 27, 2016](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-performance/windows-10-display-flickering-flashing-problem-on/7fc1f299-0252-4cf5-a50d-ef9876e3e7b5).

> So the first part was to go into msconfig and disable all services that are not Microsoft service, this would be all the Intel services that are in the list after you click the "Hide all Microsoft services". I personally disabled them all and proceeded from there. You will need to restart your system after every major step(driver installs, system changes) before proceeding, as to be sure the previous step is set.
>
> Second, go into the control panel and navigate to uninstall a program. Once there you should uninstall all of the Intel based programs. Once you uninstall the last one then your screen will bug out with squiggly lines across it. You will need to perform a hard reset by holding the power button until the system shuts down. Boot back into the system from there.
>
> Thirdly, once you are back into windows boot camp then windows 10 will begin installing a base driver for your display adapter. From this point you should not have any more screen flashing issues, however your device will not display at full brightness/quality. I was not happy with this result so i went a step further to correct it.

It only took these three steps to fix the issue and I did not experience the continuing issues nor needed to do the rest of the steps to fix anything.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.